# Identity column increment jump

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

I am experiencing something funny in my database. The primary key increases like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
1001
```

I'm using EntityFramework or sometimes LINQ to SQL.

Comment: does your insert fail at some point?

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2012 it's a bug.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/alwayson-failover-results-in-reseed-of-identity

Comment: It happens when SQL server 2012 looses its pre-allocated sequence numbers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens when SQL server 2012 loses its pre-allocated sequence numbers.

If you want to get rid of that, one option is to use traceflag:

```
DBCC TRACEON (272)
```

Another option is to use a sequence (with no caching) instead of identity:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MySeq AS int
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  NO CACHE;
```

See this: http://www.big.info/2013/01/how-to-solve-sql-server-2012-identity.html

Comment: Bless you all. thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

This is all perfectly normal. Microsoft added sequences in SQL Server 2012,  Have a look here [a link](http://www.sqlserver-training.com/sequence-breaks-gap-in-numbers-after-restart-sql-server-gap-between-numbers-after-restarting-server/-) for some explanation.

If you want to have the old behaviour, you can:

use trace flag 272 - this will cause a log record to be generated for each generated identity value. The performance of identity generation may be impacted by turning on this trace flag.
use a sequence generator with the NO CACHE setting (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)

Comment: Your first link is broken